# Understanding function defs and __name__ purpose

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started my first computer science course in a long time and encountered some code that I didn't understand. I studied python over the summer but the function definitions were simpler. Here's the code:

```
def f1(thing: list) -> None:
    thing = ['x', 1] + thing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phone = [9]
    f1(phone)
    print(phone)
```

My questions are:

1. What does the term in brackets mean i. e. '(thing: list)', more specifically, why doesn't it just say '(thing)'.
2. What does '-> None' mean?
3. What is the purpose of the if statement's first line i. e. 'if __name__ == '__main__':'
4. In class someone told me that the value of the variable 'phone' stays the same because the function definition doesn't return anything. I can't remember that being necessary for function definitions. Is that always the case?

Sorry if these questions seem a bit naive. I took the prerequisite course a long time ago and am reviewing the material in the first week of class.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: Have yu run your code? What output does it produce?